# Can CopyFileEx work directly on a drive/volume/partition

Tags: winapi, io

Does CopyFileEx only work on filesystem file handles, or can it be used to image a disk (i.e. a PhysicalDevice handle) or volumes etc.?

Answer (score 1):

CopyFileEx work only for filesystem file handles. internal CopyFileEx open files, several time call ZwQueryInformationFile(with several info classes) wich fail on PhysicalDevice handle